# Add span to tablerow

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net login form. Now I want to add a span with an icon in the td next to my input.

It looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Input with an ID</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The thing is; I only know the ID of the input. How can I "find" the td next to it, to add the span?

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest & http://api.jquery.com/next

Comment: Start with https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/

Comment: I found "closest" and "next", but since the known ID is in a different td there is no next element.

Comment: @SumitJha all my code is C#, which is not relevant for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("table #myInput").parent().next().append("html");
```

Find input id -> go parent -> next element -> append your icon

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find the content and append span to next td of that td.

```js
$('td').each(function(){
if (/\input\b/gi.test($(this).text())){
 $(this).next().append('<span>span added</span>');
}

  //\b = word boundary
  //g = global
  //i = case insensitive (if needed)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Input with an ID</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id of the `td` element then you can simply do this :

```
// For same element
$('td#input').html('<span>' + $('td#input').text() + '</span>');
// For next element
$('td#input').next().html('<span>' + 'test' + '</span>');**
```